# using spring framework's jdbcTemplate for complex filtering

Tags: mysql, spring, jdbc

I am using Spring framework's jdbcTemplate to get a list of records from the db. Now I want to add filtering to it by appending a constraint to the query. 
For eg. say the list represents persons and shows  - name, email and location

The original query is

```
String sql = "SELECT name, email, location FROM persons WHERE status = ?";
```

depending upon the filters, constraints will be appended to it

```
if(filters.containsKey("person_name")) {
   sql += " AND name LIKE '%" + filters.get("person_name") + "%'"; 
}

//similarly 
if(filters.containsKey("person_email")) {
  ....
}

//similarly 
if(filters.containsKey("person_location")) {
  ....
}
```

Thus the query will be created and executed by passing it to the query method of the jdbcTemplate object

```
this.jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new Object[] { 1 }, RowMapper<Person> rowmapper)
```

My concern is that, by using the above method, it becomes vulnerable to injection as the values against which filters are applied are directly written in the query without any escaping.

Is it possible to create the second param (arguments array) dynamically as well just like the query is built ?

Is there an alternative approach for this using jdbcTemplate ?

**Edit:** 
I am now using StringEscapeUtils.escapeSql from org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils to escape the values. But still looking for better methods or those already provided by spring if any.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe there is a better way. Take your code

```
if (filters.containsKey("person_name")) {
   sql += " AND name LIKE '%" + filters.get("person_name") + "%'";
}
```

and change it to

```
if (filters.containsKey("person_name")) {
   sql += " AND name LIKE '%?%";
}
```

You can then pass in the filters.get("person_name") in your query method. This will keep you safe from injection attacks.

In response to comment

> I thought of this as well. But how to
>   create the array of Objects (new
>   Object[] { .. }) dynamically ?

You can use a java.util.List and call the toArray() method. Kind of like this

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

List<Object> args = new ArrayList<Object>();

if (filters.containsKey("person_name")) {
   sql += " AND name LIKE '%?%";
   args.add(filters.get("person_name"));
}
```

Then when you need the arguments as an array

```
args.toArray();
```

Comment: I thought of this as well. But how to create the array of Objects (`new Object[] { .. }`) dynamically ?